# Valid Regex Not so valid in PHP

Tags: php, regex, validation

So i want to extract everything in between form tags (including the tags them selves).

The form is as below:

```
<body><br />
    <!-- 
<form method="POST" action="#">
<table style="table-layout: fixed; border: 1px solid #ffffff; " border="1">
            <!-- 
<col width="50"> --></p>
<tr style="width: 1154px; background-color: #0d56c2; vertical-align: middle; color: #ffffff; height: 70px; ">
<td style="width: 413px; text-align: center;">Calls</td>
<td style="background-color: #D6DCE5; width: 319px; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 15px;"><input type="text" name="calls" value="150" style="width: 173px;"></td>
<td style="width: 412px; padding: 5px; vertical-align: middle;"> in a period of <input name="period" value="5" style="width: 173px; ">&nbsp;<br />
                    <select name="callUnit" style="width: 100px; height: 29px; position: absolute;"><option value="hour" selected>hours</option><option value="minute" >minutes</option></select>
                </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Regex i am using is: `<form.*>[\s\S]*<\/form>` and according to [regex101](https://regex101.com/) This is a valid regular expression that should extract form tags + everthing in between.

However using the above regular expression in preg_match i get the following error: `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '['`

Comment: Regular expressions are not exactly the best utility to handle html parsing. Did you think about using a DOM parser for that?

Comment: For us the be able to help with the specific question we really would need the php code line you use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you actual issue is. For me your pattern works like charm:

```
<?php
$markup = <<<HTML
<body><br />
    <!--
<form method="POST" action="#">
<table style="table-layout: fixed; border: 1px solid #ffffff; " border="1">
            <!--
<col width="50"> --></p>
<tr style="width: 1154px; background-color: #0d56c2; vertical-align: middle; color: #ffffff; height: 70px; ">
<td style="width: 413px; text-align: center;">Calls</td>
<td style="background-color: #D6DCE5; width: 319px; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 15px;"><input type="text" name="calls" value="150" style="width: 173px;"></td>
<td style="width: 412px; padding: 5px; vertical-align: middle;"> in a period of <input name="period" value="5" style="width: 173px; ">&nbsp;<br />
                    <select name="callUnit" style="width: 100px; height: 29px; position: absolute;"><option value="hour" selected>hours</option><option value="minute" >minutes</option></select>
                </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
HTML;

preg_match('~<form.*>([\s\S]*)</form>~', $markup, $tokens);
var_dump($tokens[1]);
```

The output of that is:

```
string(829) "
<table style="table-layout: fixed; border: 1px solid #ffffff; " border="1">
            <!--
<col width="50"> --></p>
<tr style="width: 1154px; background-color: #0d56c2; vertical-align: middle; color: #ffffff; height: 70px; ">
<td style="width: 413px; text-align: center;">Calls</td>
<td style="background-color: #D6DCE5; width: 319px; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 15px;"><input type="text" name="calls" value="150" style="width: 173px;"></td>
<td style="width: 412px; padding: 5px; vertical-align: middle;"> in a period of <input name="period" value="5" style="width: 173px; ">&nbsp;<br />
                    <select name="callUnit" style="width: 100px; height: 29px; position: absolute;"><option value="hour" selected>hours</option><option value="minute" >minutes</option></select>
                </td>
</tr>
</table>
"
```

The only modification I made is to add the capture group (`(...)`) to be able to actually extract something.

You are escaping the forward slash in the closing `</form>` tag with a back slash. Most likely that is because online regex tools like `regex101` use forward slashes as standard delimiters in their patterns. Note that you can use other characters which makes the pattern easier to read, since you do *not* have to escape characters then...

---

I *suspect* that you maybe forgot to place your pattern in between delimiters?

Comment: Yup its the delimiters... It works perfectly fine now :) - I wonder why/who downvoted ...

Comment: @MaciejCygan Can't say why you received a down vote. Just ignore it, not worth  wasting a though for that. It _might_ be that someone wants to express that you should have read the documentation more closely, since the delimiters are mentioned in there.